# I need to make a multithreading program (python)

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from itertools import product
out_file = open("test.txt", 'w')
P = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p','q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]
N = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
M = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
c = int(input("Insert the number of digits you want: "))  
n = int(input("If you need number press 1: "))               
m = int(input("If you need upper letters press 1: "))            
i = []
if n == 1:
    P = P + N
if m == 1:
    P = P + M
then = time.time()
def worker():
    for i in product(P, repeat=c):      #check every possibilities
        k = ''
        for z in range(0, c):           #
            k = k + str(i[z])           #   print each possibility in a txt without parentesis or comma
    out_file.write( k + '\n')           #
    out_file.close()
    now = time.time()
    diff = str(now - then)              # To see how long does it take
    print(diff)
worker()
time.sleep(10)                  # just to check console
```

The code check every single possibility and print it out in a `test.txt` file.
It works but I really can't understand how can I speed it up. I saw it use 1 core out of my quad core CPU so I thought Multi-threading might work even though I don't know how. Please help me.
Sorry for my English, I am from Italy.

Comment: You won't speed up anything if you use threads. The GIL will only allow one active thread at a time anyway.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Almost. CPython will only allow one thread at a time to *execute python bytecode*.

Comment: So I can't speed it up in anyway?

Comment: @RolandSmith: that is implied by the nature of the question.

Comment: @Andreawu98: you can, but not with threads. With multiprocessing you will speed it up because you spawn multiple processes, but the way the code is written now it's hard. Also, it's difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Variable names such as those don't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently parallelize this code in its current state for a simple reason.

You have race condition in your worker function. If one process was to close your output file any other processes that require the file to be open will raise exceptions.

You have two options to get around this problem:

1. Remove the file close from the function and wrap all file writes in a mutex lock to ensure that file writing is only done by one process at a time.
2. Remove all file access from the worker function and have it return it's results in an array. This way you can run many workers in parallel and collate the results after all processes have completed. This way you can handle all file access from the main thread/process at the end of the code.